# C# Errors in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer-2010

Server Error in '/asppub' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.mis3200_unit4_ringu4pos_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'rblSnacks_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'rblSnacks_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.mis3200_unit4_ringu4pos_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Source Error:

```
Line 102:                    Would you like any snacks?</td>
Line 103:                <td class="style7">
Line 104:                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSnacks" runat="server"  
Line 105:                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="96px" AutoPostBack="True" 
Line 106:                        onselectedindexchanged="rblSnacks_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Source File: `c:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\asppub\MIS3200\Unit4\RingU4POS.aspx    Line: 104`

The given error message in my coding class was this:

```
 Snacks: toggle visiblity based on yes/no selection:  -2
```

The list of snacks should only be visible when somebody selects Yes (otherwise, it should be invisible). You needed to double-click the RadioButtonList to create a method which had functionality to toggle the visibility property of the CheckBoxList. For this method to work, you must enable AutoPostBack for the RadioButtonList. "

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error clearly states what the problem is.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1):

You have missed this in server side

```
protected void rblSnacks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a `rblSnacks_SelectedIndexChanged` method in a code behind that will handle the `SelectedIndexChange` event for the radio button. And if you do not need it, you should remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your code behind

```
protected void rblSnacks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have to have the `SelectedIndexChanged` in your code behind. So add this code,

```
protected void rblSnacks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code;
}
```